# Jquery jumps to iframe on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am building a site that uses an accordion panel for the main content. I set it to have all of the panels open when the page loads, but now when the page is done loading it jumps to an `<iframe>` in the middle of the page. I am very new to javascript and jquery and any help would be very appreciated. Also, with the  it takes a long time to load but without it loads quickly. Is there a way to make the load quicker with the `<iframe>`? Thank you in advance!

Here is my page: http://abigailhardindesigns.com/staging/reeves/index.html

It is jumping to a specific `<iframe>`:

```
<iframe src="http://gis.cmpdd.org/madison/" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
```

Here is the Jquery:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*-------------------- EXPANDABLE PANELS ----------------------*/
    var panelspeed = 500; //panel animate speed in milliseconds
    var totalpanels = 6; //total number of collapsible panels
    var defaultopenpanel = 1; //leave 0 for no panel open
    var accordian = false; //set panels to behave like an accordian, with one panel only ever open at once      

    var panelheight = new Array();
    var currentpanel = defaultopenpanel;
    var iconheight = parseInt($('.icon-close-open').css('height'));
    var highlightopen = true;

    $('.nav a').click(function() {
     $($(this).attr('href')).find('.expandable-panel-heading').click();
    });

    //Initialise collapsible panels
    function panelinit() {
            for (var i=1; i<=totalpanels; i++) {
                panelheight[i] = parseInt($('#cp-'+i).find('.expandable-panel-content').css('height'));
                $('#cp-'+i).find('.expandable-panel-content').css('margin-top', -panelheight[i]);
                $('#cp-'+i).find('.icon-close-open').css('background-position', '0px -'+iconheight+'px');
                $('#cp-'+i).find('.expandable-panel-content').css('margin-top', 0);
            }
    }

    $('.expandable-panel-heading').click(function() {
        var obj = $(this).next();
        var objid = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('ID').substr(3,2));
        currentpanel = objid;
        if (accordian == true) {
            resetpanels();
        }

        if (parseInt(obj.css('margin-top')) <= (panelheight[objid]*-1)) {
            obj.clearQueue();
            obj.stop();
            obj.prev().find('.icon-close-open').css('background-position', '0px -'+iconheight+'px');
            obj.animate({'margin-top':0}, panelspeed);
            if (highlightopen == true) {
                $('#cp-'+currentpanel + ' .expandable-panel-heading').addClass('header-active');
            }
        } else {
            obj.clearQueue();
            obj.stop();
            obj.prev().find('.icon-close-open').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
            obj.animate({'margin-top':(panelheight[objid]*-1)}, panelspeed);
            if (highlightopen == true) {
                $('#cp-'+currentpanel + ' .expandable-panel-heading').removeClass('header-active');
            }
        }
    });

    function resetpanels() {
        for (var i=1; i<=totalpanels; i++) {
            if (currentpanel != i) {
                $('#cp-'+i).find('.icon-close-open').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
                $('#cp-'+i).find('.expandable-panel-content').animate({'margin-top':-panelheight[i]}, panelspeed);
                if (highlightopen == true) {
                    $('#cp-'+i + ' .expandable-panel-heading').removeClass('header-active');
                }
            }
        }
    }

   //Uncomment these lines if the expandable panels are not a fixed width and need to resize
   $( window ).resize(function() {
      panelinit();
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
        panelinit();
    }); //END LOAD
}); //END READY
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a look into the iframe and the page embedded there is rather big and it loads a lot of javascript files.

I would recommend not loading it at all but to just show an image in its place with a link to that site (or replacing the image with the iframe on click). That would get rid of the unwanted scrolling as a side effect.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it's probably the easiest thing. I will do so. It does seem odd that the jquery is going straight to the `<iframe>`. I can't figure it out.

Comment: I guess that the page loaded in the iframe sets the focus on one of its elements when it is loaded. That would scroll the page down to the iframe to make the element with the focus visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);` after `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: @Clyde I tried what you suggested and nothing changed

Comment: @AbigailHardin try this instead `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);`

Comment: @AbigailHardin place at the bottom so it executes after all others are executed. Hope it works.